# My variable is not updating after changing another variable affecting it

Tags: python, variables

So I'm working a quiz on Python as a project for an Intro to Programming course.

My quiz works as intended except in the case that the quiz variable is not being affected by the new values of the blank array. On the run_quiz function I want to make the quiz variable update itself by changing the blanks to the correct answer after the user has provided it.

Here's my code:

```
#Declaration of variables
blank = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]
answers = []
tries = 5
difficulty = ""
quiz = ""

#Level 1: Easy
quiz1 = "Python is intended to be a highly " + blank[0] + " language. It is designed to have an uncluttered " + blank[1] + " layout, often using English " + blank[2] + " where other languages use " + blank[3] + ".\n"

#Level 2: Medium
quiz2 = "Python interpreters are available for many " + blank[0] + " allowing Python code to run on a wide variety of systems. " + blank[1] + " the reference implementation of Python, is " + blank[2] + " software and has a community-based development model, as do nearly all of its variant implementations. " + blank[1] + " is managed by the non-profit " + blank[3] + ".\n"

#Level 3: Hard
quiz3 = "Python features a " + blank[0] + " system and automatic " + blank[1] + " and supports multiple " + blank[2] + " including object-oriented, imperative, functional programming, and " + blank[3] + " styles. It has a large and comprehensive standard library.\n"


#Answer and quiz assignment
def assign():
  global difficulty
  global quiz
  x = 0
  while x == 0:
    user_input = raw_input("Select a difficulty, Press 1 for Easy, 2 for Medium or 3 for Hard.\n")
    if user_input == "1":
      answers.extend(["readable", "visual", "keywords", "punctuation"])
      difficulty = "Easy"
      quiz = quiz1
      x = 1
    elif user_input == "2":
      answers.extend(["operating systems", "cpython", "open source", "python software foundation"])
      difficulty = "Medium"
      quiz = quiz2
      x = 1
    elif user_input == "3":
      answers.extend(["dynamic type", "memory management", "programming paradigms", "procedural"])
      difficulty = "Hard"
      quiz = quiz3
      x = 1
    else:
      print "Error: You must select 1, 2 or 3.\n"
      x = 0

def run_quiz():
  n = 0
  global tries
  global blank
  print "Welcome to the Python Quiz! This quiz follows a fill in the blank structure. You will have 5 tries to replace the 4 blanks on the difficulty you select. Let's begin!\n"
  assign()
  print "You have slected " + difficulty + ".\n"
  print "Read the paragraph carefully and prepare to provide your answers.\n"
  while n < 4 and tries > 0:
    print quiz
    user_input = raw_input("What is your answer for " + blank[n] + "? Remember, you have " + str(tries) + " tries left.\n")
    if user_input.lower() == answers[n]:
      print "That is correct!\n"
      blank[n] = answers[n]
      n += 1
    else:
      print "That is the wrong answer. Try again!\n"
      tries -= 1
  if n == 4 or tries == 0:
    if n == 4:
      print "Congratulations! You are an expert on Python!"
    else: 
      print "You have no more tries left! You can always come back and play again!"

run_quiz()
```

I know my code has many areas of improvement but this is my first Python project so I guess that's expected.

Comment: In the while loop inside **run_quiz** after the user gets a right answer I want the variable **quiz** to update the **___#___** with the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable, `quiz`, is just a fixed string, and although it looks like it has something to do with `blanks`, it actually doesn't. What you want is 'string interpolation'. Python allows this with the `.format` method of `str` objects. This is really the crux of your question, and using string interpolation it's easy to do. I'd advise you to take some time to learn `.format`, it's an incredibly helpful function in almost any script.

I've also updated your code a bit not to use global variables, as this is generally bad practice and can lead to confusing, difficult to track bugs. It may also impair the uncluttered visual layout :). Here is your modified code, which should be working now:

```
quizzes = [
("""\
 Python is intended to be a highly {} language.\
 It is designed to have an uncluttered {} layout,\
 often using English {} where other languages use {}
""", ["readable", "visual", "keywords", "punctuation"], "Easy"),
("""\
 Python interpreters are available for many {}\
 allowing Python code to run on a wide variety of systems.\
 {} the reference implementation of Python, is {}\
 software and has a community-based development model, as\
 do nearly all of its variant implementations. {} is managed by the non-profit {}
""", ["operating systems", "cpython", "open source", "python software foundation"], "Medium"),
("""\
 Python features a {} system and automatic {} and\
 supports multiple {} including object-oriented,\
 imperative, functional programming, and\
 {} styles. It has a large and comprehensive standard library.
""", ["dynamic type", "memory management", "programming paradigms", "procedural"], "Hard")
]

#Answer and quiz assignment
def assign():
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("Select a difficulty, Press 1 for Easy, 2 for Medium or 3 for Hard.\n")
        if user_input == "1":
            return quizzes[0]
        elif user_input == "2":
            return quizzes[1]
        elif user_input == "3":
            return quizzes[2]
        else:
            print "Error: You must select 1, 2 or 3.\n"
            continue
        break

def run_quiz():
    n = 0

    #Declaration of variables
    blank = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]
    tries = 5

    print "Welcome to the Python Quiz! This quiz follows a fill in the blank structure. You will have 5 tries to replace the 4 blanks on the difficulty you select. Let's begin!\n"
    quiz, answers, difficulty = assign()
    print "You have selected {}.\n".format(difficulty)
    print "Read the paragraph carefully and prepare to provide your answers.\n"

    while n < 4 and tries > 0:
        print quiz.format(*blank)
        user_input = raw_input("What is your answer for {}? Remember, you have {} tries left.\n".format(blank[n], tries))
        if user_input.lower() == answers[n]:
            print "That is correct!\n"
            blank[n] = answers[n]
            n += 1
        else:
            print "That is the wrong answer. Try again!\n"
            tries -= 1
    if n == 4 or tries == 0:
        if n == 4:
            print "Congratulations! You are an expert on Python!"
        else: 
            print "You have no more tries left! You can always come back and play again!"

run_quiz()
```

A little more on string interpolation:

You're doing a lot of `"start of string " + str(var) + " end of string"`. This can be achieved quite simply with `"start of string {} end of string".format(var)"` - it even automatically does the `str` conversion. I've changed your `quiz` variables to have `"{}"` where either `"__1__"` etc should be displayed or the user's answer. You can then do `quiz.format(*blank*)` to print the 'most recent' version of the quiz. `*` here 'unpacks' the elements of blank into separate arguments for `format`.

If you find it more easy to learn with example usage, here are two usages of `format` in a simpler context:

```
>>> "the value of 2 + 3 is {}".format(2 + 3)
'the value of 2 + 3 is 5'
>>> a = 10
>>> "a is {}".format(a)
'a is 10'
```

I've also stored the information about each quiz in a `list` of `tuple`s, and assign now has a `return` value, rather than causing side effects. Apart from that, your code is still pretty much intact. Your original logic hasn't changed at all.

Regarding your comment about objects:

Technically, yes, `quizzes` is an object. However, as Python is a 'pure object oriented language', *everything* in Python is an object. `2` is an object. `"abc"` is an object. `[1, 2, 3]` is an object. Even functions are objects. You may be thinking in terms of JavaScript - with all of the brackets and parentheses, it kind of resembles a JS Object. However, `quizzes` is nothing more than a list (of tuples). You might also be thinking of instances of custom classes, but it's not one of those either. Instances require you to define a class first, using `class ...`.

A bit more on what `quizzes` actually is - it's a list of tuples of strings, lists of strings and strings. This is a kind of complicated type signature, but it's just a lot of nested container types really. It firstly means that each element of `quizzes` is a 'tuple'. A tuples is pretty similar to a list, except that it can't be changed in place. Really, you could almost always use a list instead of a tuple, but my rule of thumb is that a heterogenous collection (meaning stuff of different types) should generally be a tuple. Each tuple has the quiz text, the answers, and the difficulty. I've put it in an object like this as it means it can be accessed by indexing (using `quiz[n]`), rather than by a bunch of if statements which then refer to `quiz1`, `quiz2`, etc. Generally, if you find yourself naming more than about two variables which are semantically similar like this, it would be a good idea to put them in a list, so you can index, and iterate etc.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough help! I tried using the .format as it was recommended by a friend but we couldn't get around to using it since quiz2 makes two references to **___1___** which breaks the .format replace and returnts the **___4___** as an undefinded. Also, the new quiz "variable" is now what's known as an object right?

Comment: I've tried to update regarding your comment - let me know if that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Only now have I read your question properly.
You first make your strings quiz1, quiz2 an quiz3.
You only do that once.

After that you change your blanks array.
But you don't reconstruct your strings.
So they still have the old values.

Note that a copy of elements of the blanks array is made into e.g. quiz1.
That copy doesn't change automagically after the fact.
If you want to program it like this, you'll have to rebuild your quiz1, quiz2 and quiz3 strings explicitly each time you change your blanks array.

General advice: Don't use so many globals. Use function parameters instead. But for a first attempt I guess it's OK.

[edit]

A simple modification would be:

Replace your quiz, quiz1, quiz2 and quiz3 by functions get_quiz (), get_quiz1 () etc. that get the most recent version, including the altered elements of blanks.

This modification doesn't make this an elegant program. But you'll come to that with a bit more experience.

A long shot in case you wonder (but don't try to bridge that gap in one step):
In the end Quiz will probably be a class with methods and attributes, of which you have instances.

To be sure: I think that experimenting like this will make you a good programmer, more than copying some ready to go code!

Comment: I figured it was something like this, how could I go about doing this without having too much repetitive code?

Comment: @PabloVelásquez - First write something that works then look at it as a whole and find where you can make improvements, then make those improvements; then do it again...